From the middle to the middle
What term is usually used to represent what you see to the left? The numbers to the right will guide you in the right direction.

* <--> •          2(-1) 
* <-----> •       4 
* <----> •        4 
* <---> •         4  
* <------> •      2 
* <-------> •     4 
* <-> •           4 
* <--------> •    2


The answer is

 ASTRONOMICAL UNIT OR AU!

Why?

 The * symbol (a star) fittingly represents the Sun. The bullet points fittingly represents any one of the 8 planets in the solar system.


 The the <——> represents the distance between the two, whereby the more dashes represents a greater amount of distance.

So we have from top to bottom

 VENUS, JUPITER, MARS, EARTH, SATURN, URANUS, MERCURY and NEPTUNE

The numbers on the right

 Can be used to index the letters based on their positioning in the word and doing so we get V(E)-1NUS, JUP(I)TER, MAR(S), EAR(T)H, S(A)TURN, URA(N)US, MER(C)URY and N(E)PTUNE… resulting in DISTANCE.

To finish off

 The distance between planets is calculated in Astronomical Units or AU.

As for the title

 The OP mentions that such a unit is measured from the centre to  centre in the celestial bodies.


Great! But what would a term representing d between * and • be? It's a specific term where the word you found hints to. Think about something that resembles something "shiny".

@Prim3numbah better?

Yes, and the title just hints that it's measured from "middle" to "middle" (pragre)

how does V(E)-1NUS produce the letter D?

The letter before E is D
